# Computing State - Whats the different?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I'm trying to get to understand, whats the differences between this to State initializations is:

**Example 1:**

```
        const [items, setItems] = useState(() => {
            function createDataRow(id, name, quantity, unit, unitPrice, tax, discount, total) {
              return { id, name, quantity, unit, unitPrice, tax, discount, total };
            }

            let rows = [];
            rows.push(createDataRow(0, 'Lackieren', 5, 'Stk.', '120,00', 19, '-', '600,00'));
            rows.push(createDataRow(1, 'Montieren', 3, 'Stk.', '105,00', 19, '-', '315,00'));
            rows.push(createDataRow(2, 'Saugen', 3, 'Stk.', '105,00', 19, '-', '315,00'));
            return rows;
        });
```

**Example 2:**

```
        const [items, setItems] = useState(() => {
          return [
              { id: 1, name: 'Items One' },
              { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
              { id: 3, name: 'Items 3' },
            ];
        });
```

I'm asking this, because if I'm using the Example one, the State is somehow not mutable. However, if I use the Example 2 my State is indeed mutable.

#### Edit

As requested, this is a Example of my Test.

[image: Edit sharp-paper-qbrrh]

Comment: The `items` constant in example 2 may be mutable, but it wont trigger a re-render, which is what you want on state change.

Comment: There's nothing different between those two approaches. They should both make mutable data (though you should never actually mutate the state).

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between the two. Can you post the entire code of how you're trying to mutate ?

Comment: @DeanJames could you maybe explain a little more on why the State in example 2 would never trigger a re-render ? 

@ScottyJamison what do you mean with "you should never actually mutate the state" mutating the state via. `setItems` would be the only right way doing it. Sorry if I didn't get you right.

Comment: Both functions return a new array of new objects. They might use different syntax and helper functions, but there's no difference about the usage of `items` and `setItems`.

Comment: @DeanJames This is not a `setState` callback, it's lazy `useState` initialisation. There is no mutation, the function is pure.

Comment: As requested I provided an Example, which I attached on my Question above. After digging little more, I'm really not sure if my problems are really coming from the State. Thanks again :)

Comment: Going to echo what others are saying here: there's nothing different. Both initializers return an array of objects. Both states are equally mutable.